# PostgreSQL: permission denied for sequence posts_post_id_seq

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL, and I'm testing a NodeJS/React app on cPanel.

I'm able to read data from the PostgresSQL database, but when I try to insert data into it I get the error "permission denied for sequence posts_post_id_seq". `posts` is the table name and `post_id` is the PK.

In node, I establish the connection to the database like so:

`postgresql://${process.env.DB_USER_PROD}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD_PROD}@${process.env.DB_HOST_PROD}/${process.env.DB_NAME_PROD}`

I have checked every value in the string above and it is correct; as stated above, I can fetch data from Node using `SELECT`. `DB_USER_PROD` value is **lemon_admin** and in the screenshot below of phpPgAdmin I see that this user have all privileges

[image]

the server code for inserting is this:

```
app.post('/api/postsdb', async (req, res) => {
   
    const {title, content, author} = req.body
    try {
        const postQuery = 'INSERT INTO posts(title, author, content) VALUES($1, $2, $3)'
        await pool.query(postQuery, [title, author, content])
       
        return res.send({status: 'ok', msg:'alrigth'})
    } catch (error) {
       
        return  res.send({status: 'failed', msg: error.message})
    }   
})
```

This works locally with Postbird.

Since I am new to PG, it's very possible that Im missig something

I only have access to phpPgAdmin. I dont have SSH access.

How can I grant permission for this user to not only SELECT, but also to INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE? I have to do it from phpPgAdmin, please.

Thanks

Comment: It seems you *do* have `INSERT` permissions on that table, what you do not have are [the `USAGE` or `UPDATE` permissions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) on the `posts_post_id_seq` **sequence**.

Comment: I appreciate your input. How can I fix it? I read the article you linked, but it is not very clear to me. thanks

Comment: Btw: this is one of the reasons `identity` columns are [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) over `serial` columns

Comment: yes, i'm changing to uuid. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grant INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE use:

```
GRANT UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON posts TO username;
```

But it looks like table has some column which is fed by sequence. And user needs to have permission to use that sequence.

```
GRANT USAGE, SELECT ON SEQUENCE posts_post_id_seq TO username;
```

Also note that none of the above code has schema, do not forget to add or select before running it.